# Помогите доделать игру на js

Tags: javascript

Игра называется крестики-нолики. В ней осталось доделать "ничью".

Для этого надо чтобы при заполнении всех тегов div возможность их перезаполнять отсутствовала.

Подскажите, как это делается?

```js
var name1;
var name2 = 'player2';
window.onload = function() {
  name1 = prompt('Введите свое имя', 'player1');
  name2 = prompt('Введите свое имя', 'player2');
  alert('Игра началась');
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    document.getElementById("game").innerHTML += '<div class="block"></div>'
  }
  var turn = 0;
  document.getElementById("game").onclick = function(e) {
    if (event.target.className == 'block') {
      if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        event.target.innerHTML = 'x';
        document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = "Ход: " + name2;
      } else {
        event.target.innerHTML = 'o';
        document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = "Ход: " + name1;
      }
      turn++;
      checkWinner();
    }
  }

  function checkWinner() {
    var allblock = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
    if (allblock[0].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[1].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[2].innerHTML == 'x') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name1;
    if (allblock[3].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[4].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[5].innerHTML == 'x') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name1;
    if (allblock[6].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[7].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[8].innerHTML == 'x') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name1;
    if (allblock[0].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[3].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[6].innerHTML == 'x') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name1;
    if (allblock[1].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[4].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[7].innerHTML == 'x') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name1;
    if (allblock[2].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[5].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[8].innerHTML == 'x') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name1;
    if (allblock[0].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[4].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[8].innerHTML == 'x') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name1;
    if (allblock[6].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[4].innerHTML == 'x' && allblock[2].innerHTML == 'x') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name1;

    if (allblock[0].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[1].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[2].innerHTML == 'o') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name2;
    if (allblock[3].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[4].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[5].innerHTML == 'o') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name2;
    if (allblock[6].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[7].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[8].innerHTML == 'o') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name2;
    if (allblock[0].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[3].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[6].innerHTML == 'o') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name2;
    if (allblock[1].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[4].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[7].innerHTML == 'o') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name2;
    if (allblock[2].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[5].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[8].innerHTML == 'o') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name2;
    if (allblock[0].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[4].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[8].innerHTML == 'o') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name2;
    if (allblock[6].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[4].innerHTML == 'o' && allblock[2].innerHTML == 'o') document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: ' + name2;

  }
  restart.onclick = function() {
    name1 = prompt('Введите свое имя', 'player1');
    name2 = prompt('Введите свое имя', 'player2');
    alert('Игра началась');
    document.getElementsByClassName('block')[0].innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementsByClassName('block')[1].innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementsByClassName('block')[2].innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementsByClassName('block')[3].innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementsByClassName('block')[4].innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementsByClassName('block')[5].innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementsByClassName('block')[6].innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementsByClassName('block')[7].innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementsByClassName('block')[8].innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = "Ход: ";
    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = 'победитель: '
  }
}
```

```css
#game {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: orangered;
}

.block {
  width: 50;
  height: 50;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#restart {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid orangered;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
</div>
<b><p id="player">Ход:</p></b>
<b><p id="winner">Победитель:</p></b>
<div id="restart">Restart</div>
```

Comment: Я не читал ваше решение, но вообще должно быть так: при каждом проставлении ноля/крестика смотреть на все ячейки и если все заполнены блокируем.